# Why my constructor injection doesn't work?

Tags: spring

I have a Spring service

```
@Suppress("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
@Service
class RegulationExtractor : AbstractExtractor {

    constructor(@Autowired fileContract: FileContract, @Autowired dictionaryContractImpl: DictionaryContractImpl, @Autowired regulationContractImpl: RegulationContractImpl) :
            super(fileContract, dictionaryContractImpl, regulationContractImpl) {
    }


}
```

In the class hierarchy shown here
https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/358947aa94987138bc4c73178f7b3ae5
and it doesn't work

```
   var fileContract: FileContract
   var dictionaryContractImpl: DictionaryContractImpl
   var regulationContractImpl: RegulationContractImpl
```

are still = null, why?

Comment: Are you getting exception stacktrace when runng the application?

Comment: @Ismail only NPE while accessing described fields. They aren't instantiated